# Estimate Shipping and Tax issue in magento

Tags: magento

When I add a product to my Shopping Cart, it does not display the standard shipping calculation. But once I proceed to the checkout page, and edit the shopping cart it shows the estimate price calculation.

How can I display the shipping when a visitor adds the product to the shopping cart?

Answer (score 4):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to ask.  This may be a shot in the dark, but when you first get to the cart, in order to get a shipping quote, you need to enter in your zip code.  Perhaps if you've already gotten into the checkout process and have entered in an address, at that point since you've entered in a zip code already maybe the shopping cart page recognizes that?